# Почему не загружается шрифт с другого домена?

Tags: вёрстка

Есть сайт на вордпрессе. Залил туда кастомный шрифт, подключил, всё работает. Подключил так:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "CyrillicOldBold";
src: url("/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/CyrillicOldBold.eot");
src: url("/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/CyrillicOldBold.eot?#iefix")format("embedded-opentype"),
url("/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/CyrillicOldBold.woff") format("woff"),
url("/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/CyrillicOldBold.ttf") format("truetype");
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
}
```

Но работает только когда перехожу на сайт по дефолтному домену:
`http://myazin1m.bget.ru/`

Также я купил доменное имя в зоне .рф, и прикрепил его к сайту.
Так вот при переходе по `http://банянапарковом.рф/` шрифт отваливается.
Что делать? Шрифт применён к заголовку.

```
Font from origin 'http://myazin1m.bget.ru' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://xn--80aaabi1cpdanbho9r.xn--p1ai' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Консоль выдаёт ошибку кросдоменного запроса.

Comment: может на хостинге стоит защита вроде хот-линкинга? дайте доступ рф-домену в настройках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо определиться какой домен будет основным, и сделать редирект в .htaccess с дополнительных доменов на основной. Прописать основной домен в настройках WP и в robots.txt как host. А то сейчас у Вас все ссылки с рф домена ведут на другой сайт.